# How to send message to every server bot is in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I want that my bot sends a message to every guild it's in, I can't get it to work though. I really need some help about that.

Comment: you can use the [`client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) map to cycle through each guild your bot is a member in.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but if you create a json file and fill with the server'id and a channel'id in that server that you want to send a message to.
example:

```
[
{"guildId":"firstserver'id",
 "channelId":"aChannelInThatServer"
}
{"guildId":"secondserver'id",
 "channelId":"aChannelInThatServer"
}
......
]
```

and then create a command that loops through this file and checks if the client is in those server and if it's in a server, it should check if that channel exists in that guild , and if it does, it finally send the message there.
in theory this should work but i still don't know if that is possible
again check the [discord.js documents](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) to learn more about clients and guilds

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but here:

```
bot.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
    console.log(guild.name);
    let annmess = args.join(" ").slice(18)
    if (!annmess) return message.channel.send("Specify a message to announce")
    try {
      guild.channels.cache
        .find(x => x.name.includes("general" && "main" && "main-chat" && "chat" && "lounge"))
        .send(annmess);
    } catch {
      console.log("Message wasn't sent for " + guild.name);
    }
  });
```

What this does is basically cache each server the bot is in, and automatically sends a message to any channel containing "general", "main", "main-chat" and "chat". (You can add more if you want)